# How can I find the nth phone number using dictionary?

Tags: python

My problem is finding nth phone number using dictionary(Python).

`phonedict = {‘kim’: ‘344-7944’, ......., ‘choi’: ‘544-2376’}`, containing 10 items. 
Write a Python code that sorts the keys in ascending order, and print out the phone number of 5-th person.

How can I find this? Even I tried for finding answer, I'm still not find the answer.
I call for help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: How do you iterate a dict? How to you access dict information?

Comment: well first you need to get the keys of the dict......then sort them in order......then pick the nth key and use that to look up the dictionary

Comment: Also: look up `enumerate`

Comment: Is this an exercise for your programming class? Please show what have you tried so far, not ask people to code it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following dictionary.

`phone = {'ar': 123123, 'qw': 3453453, 'cv':34234, 'dd': 56757675, 'aa': 43534534, 'bb': 87897675}`

fifth element lies at 4 index of sorted keys of phone

`phonedict[sorted(phonedict)[4]]`

`output: 56757675`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try sorting the keys first, maybe just using `sorted` then accessing the element that you need:

```
phone_dict = {
  'd': '1234-1233',
  'e': '1234-1234',
  'f': '1234-1235',
  'a': '1234-1230',
  'b': '1234-1231',
  'g': '1234-1236',
  'h': '1234-1237',
  'c': '1234-1232'
}

sorted_keys = sorted(phone_dict.keys())

pos = 4 # 5th position since arrays start at index 0
print(phone_dict.get(sorted_keys[5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike lists or tuples, dictionaries are data structures whose elements (pairs of key-values) cannot be sorted. To get access to the number of the fifth person (in an ordered list) you can try the following code:

```
keys = list(phonedict.keys())
keys.sort()
print(phonedict[keys[int(len(keys)/2)-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
phone = {'ar': 123123, 'qw': 3453453, 'cv':34234, 'dd': 56757675, 'aa': 43534534, 'bb': 87897675}
numlist = []
for i in phone:
    numlist.append(phone[i])
numlist = numlist.sort()
print(numlist)
print(numlist[4])
```